# Optimising Firebase's power consumption on mobiles

Tags: mobile, power-management, battery, firebase

For Firebase-based mobile applications in which latencies of ~1 minute (or manual sync) are acceptable, will power consumption be optimal? Is it possible and does it make sense to adjust keep-alives, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase is optimized for real-time communication (meaning as low latency as possible).  While I have no reason to suspect it'll be a power hog, we haven't (yet) optimized for power consumption or done any in-depth testing.

Feel free to email support@firebase.com if you do any testing on your own and want to share your findings.

Comment: hi, any news on these power optimisations ?

Comment: It's websockets. That's a pretty good reason to suspect high power consumption lol